# Energy of spin in Stern Gerlach

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, superposition

Consider a Stern Gerlach devise. If the spin of the Ag atom makes an angle of say 30 grades according the magnet's up direction would Ag come out in the up or down ray on the plate behind? I consider it (Ag spin) to be in superposition of up and down spin and so there is probability to end in either rays.
What Energy (kinetic) would Ag loose (or take?) in either cases (this is the important question!) Please take in mind that I would like to adhere only to Copenhagen interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

A spin 1/2 state quantized along a polar angle theta is:

$$ |\theta\rangle = \cos{\theta/2}|\uparrow\rangle + \sin{\theta/2}|\downarrow\rangle $$

The expectation value of the energy is:

$$ \langle E \rangle  = \langle\theta|\hat H|\theta\rangle $$

Comment: Thank you for this. So the probability is up -> cos^2(15) and down sin^2(15). But what is the Energy for each case? I dont need the mean value but to understand is there a difference?

Comment: @MErcury: what is the hamiltonian? The up and down states are eigenstates, do the energy difference is the difference in the eigenvalues.

Comment: The problem is that one starts in superposion up+down spin.

Comment: Say if the spin is up (say left place on the plate) and the velocity before the SG didnt change, than one must conclude that Ag spin was up. If velocity is changed the spin was down and changed to up. So it turns out that Ag spin was not in fact a superposition but a statistical mixture. {I think - after another question here before 3-4 days - that the magnet doesnt change and only the speed of the Ag and the spin z component change).

Comment: there's not enough information in the problem. What's the beam energy, what's the field, what's the hamiltonian, what's the initial state?

Comment: I am not considering a beam but single Ag atom with spin 30 grades (in can be anything but not 0 or 180) along the field. So the spin is superposition up+down along the field. The strength of field is irrelevant. Its speed is fixed as much as Heisenberg allows.